# How to define constexpr function inside class?

Tags: c++, function, class, constexpr

I have class and i want to define const int array as variable, so i need constexpr function but i cannot figure out why my code does not compiles when the function is class member. It only compiles when the function is outside the class.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

template<int T>
class Test
{
    constexpr uint32_t pow(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
    {
        uint32_t c = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            c *= a;
        return c;
    }

    float arr[pow(2, T)][T];
}

int main()
{
    Test<4> test_class;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler needs to be able to determine the array size without having access to an object of type `Test`; it can only do so, if the function is `static`; non-static member functions can only be called given an object of the type it's part of, e.g. `Test<2> tst; tst.pow(1,2);`

Comment: @fabian Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. I overlooked the first snippet and didn't realize that OP has already tried that.

Comment: *"what is the reason for that ?"* - Your compiler [told you](https://godbolt.org/z/GqbMEna7a): *"a call of a non-static member function requires an object"*.

Answer (score 4):

The size of the array has to be known at compile time.

Since `pow` is a non static method you must have a `this` object in order to call it, and there is none at compile time.

If you change it to a static method it will work:

```
template<int dim>
struct Test
{
    static constexpr int pow(int first, int second)
    {
        int out = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < second; i++)
            out *= first;
        return out;
    }

    float arr[pow(2, dim)][dim];
};

int main()
{
    Test<2> tst;
}
```